# How to display an alert in Cocos2dx for Windows XNA?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, cocos2d-x

Currently i'm working in cocos2d-x for Windows XNA.I'm having problem in displaying alerts or message boxes.Can any one help me in this regard.

Comment: what do you want? give more info... is windows based? phone based? integrated with the app? a system based message?

Comment: I'm trying to create a game in Windows-Phone-7 using Cocos2d-x for XNA.But i can't show message boxes/alerts in that.I hope that's clear.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Augustine : Did you try CCAssert or CCMessageBox ? ?

Answer (score 0):

If you add reference System.Windows you could use:

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
```